# Removing double quotes for specific fields in JSON data using groovy script

Tags: json, groovy

using below groovy script I am able to remove double quotes for the specific fields, but if the structure is an array, This script not working. Please help me on this.

Input:

```
[
{
    "SalesOrder": "02",
    "Dealer": "1",
    "Purchase": "B",
    "CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
    "Status": "Open",
    "Overall": "A",
    "OverallTotal": "A",
    "Amount": "1000.0"
    
},
{
    "SalesOrder": "03",
    "Dealer": "2",
    "Purchase": "B",
    "CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
    "Status": "Open",
    "Overall": "A",
    "OverallTotal": "A",
    "Amount": "1000.0"
},
{
"SalesOrder": "04",
    "Dealer": "3",
    "Purchase": "B",
    "CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
    "Status": "Open",
    "Overall": "A",
    "OverallTotal": "A",
    "Amount": "1000.0"
}


  ]
```

Groovy script:`

```
  import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import groovy.json.*
  import java.util.*;
def Message processData(Message message)
 {
def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
 def jsonDataObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(body);
 if(jsonDataObject.Amount!=null)
  { 
  jsonDataObject.Amount = convertToFloat(jsonDataObject.Amount);
    }
   message.setBody(new JsonBuilder(jsonDataObject).toPrettyString())
   return message
   static Object convertToFloat(Object inputValue){
    if(inputValue.isNumber()){
      return inputValue.toFloat();
    }else{
      return inputValue;
    }
     }
```

Expected output is, for the amount field double quotes should get remove and then display the output. Below is the output code.

Output:

```
[
  {
 "SalesOrder": "02",
  "Dealer": "1",
   "Purchase": "B",
  "CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
  "Status": "Open",
  "Overall": "A",
  "OverallTotal": "A",
  "Amount": 1000.0

  },
  {
"SalesOrder": "03",
"Dealer": "2",
"Purchase": "B",
"CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
"Status": "Open",
"Overall": "A",
"OverallTotal": "A",
"Amount": 1000.0
  },
  {
"SalesOrder": "04",
"Dealer": "3",
"Purchase": "B",
"CreationDate": "2021-08-17",
"Status": "Open",
"Overall": "A",
"OverallTotal": "A",
"Amount": 1000.0
  }


  ]
```

Comment: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_a_list

Comment: could you please help me with sample code, I am quite confusing here.